# Regarding struct variable declaration in C vrs C++

Tags: c++, c, struct

in C

```
   struct node {
          int x;
   };

   node *y; // incorrect
   struct node *y; // correct
```

in C++

```
   struct node{
         int x;
   };

   node *y; // correct
   y = new node; // correct
```

Question: Why is the tag name acceptable to create a pointer in C++ not in C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the C++ standard says so, and the C standard doesn't.

I would say that C++ made the change to make classes easier to use (remember, classes and structs are fundamentally the same thing in C++; they only differ in default visibility), and C didn't follow suit because that would break tons of existing C code.

Comment: That sounds acceptable, just wanted to confirm. Also another question, when we call new in C++, the constructor is called, so when we use new operator with struct, is a constructor called too?

Comment: @codeymodey normally a struct wouldn't have a constructor (just by convention, you'd use a class for anything that did). But if it does have one, it will be called.

Comment: @hobbs struct and class are same in c++ except the public access specifier for all members of structures. So compiler does provide  a default constructor for structure too as it provide for class.

Comment: @codeymodey since in c++ new is an operator what it does internally is allocate memory and calls the default constructor of class. So it behaves same for strcut too.  just to add and new can also be overloaded and you can have a custom memory allocation code for your class.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is not just because the standard says so, C++ actually has [namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) while the `struct` keyword allowed for a primitive form of namespace in C which allowed you to have a struct and a non-struct identifier with the same name. We can see this primitive form of a namespace from the C99 draft standard section `6.2.3` *Name spaces of identifiers* which says:

> If more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible at any point in a
>   translation unit, the syntactic context disambiguates uses that refer to different entities.
>   Thus, there are separate name spaces for various categories of identifiers, as follows:

and has the following bullets:

> — label names (disambiguated by the syntax of the label declaration and use);
>
> — the tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (disambiguated by following any24)
>   of the keywords struct, union, or enum);
>
> — the members of structures or unions; each structure or union has a separate name
>   space for its members (disambiguated by the type of the expression used to access the
>   member via the . or -> operator);
>
> — all other identifiers, called ordinary identifiers (declared in ordinary declarators or as enumeration constants).

I could make up an example but [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) gives us a great example with [stat](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html) which is both a *function* and a *struct*:

```
int stat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);
    ^^^^                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: what does this mean " which allowed you to have a struct and a non-struct identifier with the same name" could you share an example?

Comment: Okay, so in C it allowed to have both struct tag name and function name or variable name with same name..so how is it a problem in C++? (feel free to correct me)

Comment: @codeymodey just like in C in C++ you would be forced to use `struct` as we can see from this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f38745fb942abc77) but you would not do that in C++ you would use a namespace whereas in C you don't have that option and therefore `struct` serves a purpose as a primitive namespace mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the way **node* y** in C, just

```
typedef struct node {
    int x;
} node;
```